# Javascript to stop execution after a cell contains only 0;

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am required to stop the execution of the JavaScript  function as soon as any of the table cells contains a zero. I tried my best, but nothing seems to work. I can not understand why is it not working.

```js
function ZeroCheck(IDTable) {

  var myData = [];
  $('#' + IDTable).find("tr:gt(0)").each(function(i, row) {

    var oRow = [];
    $(row).find("td").each(function(j, cell) {

      if ($(cell).text() == '0') {
        alert('Please correct input. There should not be a 0 in any cell');
        return false;
      }

      oRow.push(parseFloat($(cell).text()));
    });
    myData.push(oRow);
  });
};
```

Comment: It's because you have not broken the outer each, you probably need to set a flag in the inner each and when you return out of that loop, you need to check in the outer loop and return too

Comment: Your find is executing a function for each cell.  That function quite happily returns false, which is ignored.  `each` then continues with the next cell.  Don't use `each` here, use a normal loop.  `var cells = $('#' + IDTable).find("tr:gt(0)"); for(i = 0; i < cells.size(); i++) { if (!testCell(cells[i]) { break; } }`

Comment: `function ZeroCheck(IDTable) {
  var myData = [];
  var rows = document.getElementById(IDTable).rows;
  for (var i = 1; i<rows.length;i++) {
    var oRow = [];
    for (var j=0;j<rows[i].cells.length;j++) {
      var val = rows[i].cell[j].innerText;
      if (val == '0') {
        alert('Please correct input. There should not be a 0 in any cell');
        return false;
      }
      oRow.push(parseFloat(val);
    }
    myData.push(oRow);
  }
}`

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this:

```
function ZeroCheck(IDTable) {
  let isZeroDetectted = false;
  let myData = [];
  $('#' + IDTable).find("tr:gt(0)").each(function(i, row) {

    let oRow = [];
    $(row).find("td").each(function(j, cell) {
     if ($(cell).text() == '0') {
      alert('Please correct input. There should not be a 0 in any cell');
      isZeroDetectted = true;
      return false;
    }
    oRow.push(parseFloat($(cell).text()));
  });
  if(isZeroDetectted){
    return false;
  }
  myData.push(oRow);
});};
```

Answer (score 0):

Corrected and Used version of mplungjan suggested piece of code. I find this code better than my one in my question. It is self-explanatory, fairly easy and gives more control over rows and columns.

function calculateAHP(IDTable){

```
var myData = []; 
var rows = document.getElementById(IDTable).rows; 

for (var i = 1; i<rows.length;i++) { 

     var oRow = []; 

     for ( var j=1; j<rows[i].cells.length; j++)  { 

          var val = rows[i].cells[j].innerText; 
          if (parseFloat(val) == 0)  { 
                alert('Please correct input. There should not be a 0 in any cell'); 
               return false; 
            } 
            oRow.push(parseFloat(val)); 
         } 

     myData.push(oRow); 
    }
```

};